# OmniAuth Twitter - Setting up a 'Sign Up' callback + page upon user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, callback, omniauth

I've just setup the omniauth twitter gem and wanted to accomplish two things. The first is that I wanted to create a custom callback. So right after the user goes through the preliminary steps to authenticate via Twitter I wanted to bring them to a page that would require them to enter additional information from my user model `:first_name`, `last_name`. This was a bit easier with Facebook's API being that  it already came with the aforementioned data, so all I had to do was add this method to my `user.rb` file:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
    end
  end
```

But as you know Twitter requires that user's enter their full name and I'm trying to avoid that nightmare of parsing what they entered, properly separating the text, and passing my custom validations.

My `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` file was created following the omniauth wiki and currently looks like this for Facebook signup request:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

How would I create a custom controller/view and callback specifically for Twitter users that would accomplish what I'm trying to do?